# Angular 10 : Is there any way to get the selected DataList object

Tags: html, angular, typescript, html-datalist

Was creating an Input field with DataList. I was trying to get the object associated with selected option. I was able to get the selected value but not the whole object. I saw some earlier posts where the Datalist items are Unique. In such case we can filter the result based on the selected item & we have only one object corresponding to the selected value.

In my case the DataList items are not unique.

public userDetails: Array  = [
{userID: 1, userName: 'user 1'}, {userID: 2, userName: 'user 2'}, {userID: 11, userName: 'user 1'}]

Here the items that we are displaying is userName and it's not unique. I need to get the userID corresponding to selected item.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" list="datalist1"/>
<datalist id="datalist1">
     <option *ngFor="let user of userDetails" [value]="user.displayName" (click)="selected(user)">
         {{ user.displayName }}
     </option>
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this :

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" list="datalist1" [(ngModel)]='currentUser' (change)="selected(currentUser)"/>
<datalist id="datalist1">
     <option *ngFor="let user of userDetails" [value]="user.displayName">
         {{ user.displayName }}
     </option>
</datalist>
```

and then in `component.ts` :

```
selected(item){
    console.log('selected items : ',item)
    this.selctedUser = this.userDetails.filter((user)=>user.displayName.includes(item))

  }
```

ofcourse you'll have to update the field using which you want to find the users.
here is a sample demo : [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hzt3tx?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: I have already tried this solution. For me the issue is list items are not unique.

Comment: Did you check the demo ? It gives you all the elements matching selected item . If this is not what you want then elaborate your question.. what you want to Achieve

Comment: Yes I have checked your demo. Thanks for your answer. I was able to retrieve all elements matching the selected item. But what I need is to get object of selected item only. I have elaborated my question hope it's more readable now.